# How to extend permission scope GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch

Tags: ios, google-calendar-api, google-api-objc-client

I have an application which is using `GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch` to do the login.

Initially the scope was just using `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email`, so the user is already logged in with this permission.

I want to ask for new permissions for `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar`

So when it retrieves the auth object from the keychain:

```
GTMOAuth2Authentication *auth = [GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch authForGoogleFromKeychainForName:keychainItemName
                                                                                              clientID:clientID
                                                                                          clientSecret:clientSecret];
```

and this new permission is not in the scope of the `auth` object, I try to present again the `GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch` to extend the scope, but it requires the user to enter credentials again.

I would expect this controller to just ask for the approval of this new permission.

How can I achieve this behaviour? Is it possible with the [google-api-objectivec-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client/wiki)

UPDATE:

I have been able to get closer by using `GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch`'s `swapInCookies` & `swapOutCookies` methods..

For a new installation, these methods would open again the same controller (webview for signing in) and the second time it just asks for permissions, keeping the user away from entering his credentials again.

But the problem now is that the current app, doesn´t `swapOutCookies` when the login is completed, so there are no cookies to be swapped into the webview, so it asks for login, when the user was supposed to be already logged in.

Answer (score 0):

You can append new scopes using the `GIDSignIn` shared instance by calling `scopes` and then calling `signIn` to request consent. More information can be found on the [Requesting additional scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/additional-scopes) in the iOS Google Identity documentation.

An example provided for requesting additional scope would be

```
NSString *driveScope = @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly";
NSArray *currentScopes = [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].scopes;
[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].scopes = [currentScopes arrayByAddingObject:driveScope];

[[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signIn];
```

Comment: What if I don´t have the `GIDSignIn` package in the project?? Isn´t it possible to do it with the `GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch`? (It is the tool the project I´m extending functionality to is using.)

Comment: I think you're using Google Toolkit for Mac? I checked the oAuth2 client repo of the library and you may be able to set the scope by using `GTMOAuth2SignIn`.`standardGoogleAuthenticationForScope`. Though I can't be sure if it has the same flexibility as `GIDSignIn`, you may want to try this out. Hopefully this can solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for helping... however, that method returns a `GTMOAuth2Authentication` which I´m already recovering with `GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch` ->  `authForGoogleFromKeychainForName:clientID:clientSecret:`;
So it doesn´t change the behaviour of the GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch controller I´m presenting.
It did give me an idea to use controllerWithAuthentication:authorizationURL:keychainItemName:completionHandler
but it asks for credentials again.
The only thing that seems to do the trick is to swapIn the cookies if they have been previously swapped out...